# How do you link accounts for Swordcoast adventures?

Tags: neverwinter, sword-coast-adventures

I recently started playing neverwinter again, and am at the point where I want to play swordcoast adventures. However, when I log into the gateway, I get this message:

[image: Gateway]

And when I click the link to link accounts, this page opens:

[image]

I cant see any information on this page that relates to the neverwinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted PWE support and they walked me through the process. I was logging in with my username, and apparently it was was referencing an old account that I never finished making. I used my email address, and the system started acting as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be at all helpful, but I did it by creating an ark account on my computer, and then logging in on my xbox one, which is what I play Neverwinter on, tell me if this is helpful or not please.

Comment: I'm only on computer, so that doesn't help me. However it may help someone else

Comment: ok, but it may be the same deal, you click link accounts and then sign in when it asks you to. sorry i couldn't be of help. you should put a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can go to games, and then there is a list of all their games, including neverwinter. If you have an account, sign into it, and then there should be some option to link accounts if you go into your profile, you could also go to the Ark forums and ask for more directions there.